# Apply django's template filters inside a `js` script on an object's attribute

Tags: javascript, json, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I'm unable to use django's template filters inside a `js` script on an object's attribute.

This piece of code returns a `js` SyntaxError:

```
<script>
    {{ obj.geometry.geojson | safe }}
</script>
```

While if the filter is applied on an object, no error is thrown:

```
<script>
    {{ obj | safe }}
</script>
```

The content of the `GeoJson` file above is shown below:

```
{ "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 3, 36 ], ... }
```

I obviously don't want to have the quote character (`"`) escaped into a (`&quot;`) so I can `JSON.parse()` it later to convert it from a string into an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view generate new string of GeoJson and pass it to template similar below:

```
return render(
           request,
           'my_template.html',
           {'obj': obj, 'geo_json': json.dumps(obj.geometry.geojson)}
       )
```

Now everywhere you need GeoJson content use it same as below:

```
<script>
    {{ geo_json | safe }}
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

Also you can handling this by [context-processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext) or [template-tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/), but this ways maybe hard and unnecessary...

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, since the output is still escaped in the `JS` variable.

Comment: Is there a way to change the json field directly from `DetailView::get_context_data()` and pass it to the template? `serialize('geojson', [context['object']])` didn't give the expected result.

Comment: Yes, by some way this action is possible but these ways not short way

Comment: Yes that issue seems fixed now that I'm using your code but it wasn't really necessary to json dump it from the view to the template, since the string is escaped in the template (where `{{ obj | safe }}` was necessary).